# Back button Launches Splash Screen

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I am developing Phonegap 2.7.0 + Android Application.
Problem is when I am on index.html page of my application and I press back button of device  it Launches Splash Screen and ReInitiate Application.

Comment: Actually I am newb to Phonegap and dont know how to code in android.
I am seeking for any solution from phonegap side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Phonegap side, you could attach a handler function to the backbutton, something like this:

```
function exitApp() {
    console.log("Exiting app");
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}

function onPressBack(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to quit?", function(result){
        if(result == 2){
            exitApp();
        }
    }, 'Quit My App', 'Cancel,Ok');
}

function deviceready() {
    $(document).bind('backbutton', onPressBack);
}
$(document).bind('deviceready', deviceready);
```

If you're using jQuery Mobile for paging, you can keep track of whether it's the first page being shown and therefore whether to show the exit dialog - see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258550/back-button-handler-in-jquery-mobile-android-phonegap/17262220#17262220)

Comment: I have used your code for application exit. it works fine. 
I used it in home.html but it prevents default back button behaviour throughout all my application pages. Thats is issue for me now.

Comment: You could add a monitor or counter to determine if the first/main application page is the one being shown and therefore whether, on pressing the back button, to exit or simply go back. That's similar behaviour to my [jQuery mobile back button example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258550/back-button-handler-in-jquery-mobile-android-phonegap/17262220#17262220)

Comment: for my example I am placing backbutton code in home.html
but it will prevents default back button behaviour throughout the application in Android.

Comment: so are you saying you have multiple HTML files (e.g. home.html, anotherpage.html, differentpage.html) and you only want the back button to exit if the current page is home.html? Otherwise, if the current page is a differnt page, just go back?

Answer (score 2):

You should call `finish()` or `this.finish()` after calling the `startActivity(intent)` method.

Something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, activityToBeCalled.class) ;
startActivity(intent) ;
finish() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `finish()` in splash screen activity

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
  protected void onPause()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
  }
```

add this event to your splash activity class.

Edit: you can add activity events by right clicking and following "Source->Overwrite/Implements Methods...".

http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

and then you should add this event to your webview activty

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    // do not finish app use webview controls to go preview webpage.
}
```